# RingCentral ExtensionCallLogResponse Object for Calls

Tags: c#, api, calllog, ringcentral

I am new to using RingCentral and in using API calls.

I am using RingCentral's C# nuget example to help me along with trying to get both outgoing and incoming call logs with their legs.

So far I am trying to get the incoming calls by using

```
ExtensionCallLogResponse callLogsInBound = await mainAccount.CallLog().List(new {
  dateFrom = monday.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"),
  dateTo = monday.AddDays(5),
  view = "Detailed",
  direction = "Inbound"
});
```

This is a nested, object with Navigation information, paging info, and multiple records (Calls).
 What is the best way to read this information into a gridview for reporting UserNames, Call Counts, Legs of calls?
I have tried converting this object to a datatable, but I have not had any success yet, and I am wondering if there is a better way?
Thanks,
K.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to avoid reading a big chunk or the entire call log which would force you to use the navigation data to navigate between pages.

One way is to read the call log of each extension for a short period of time (fromDate and toDate) and set the perPage parameter to maximum of 1000 items. (use the User Call Log endpoint)

If you want to read the entire company call log using the Company Call Log endpoint, then specified even shorter period of time to ensure it would fit the 1000 items per page.

To add the data to your database, I am not sure what type of database you are thinking of, but you can make e.g. a .csv format then parse the response to extract the data you want to keep. See the API reference for response information.

```
// e.g.
var callLogs = await rc.Restapi().Account().Extension(1234567890).CallLog().List(parameters);
var csv = "id,uri,result";
foreach(var record in callLogs.records)
{
  csv += "\r\n" + record.id + "," + record.uri + "," + record.result;
}
System.Console.WriteLine(csv);
```

Is the Username you mentioned the name of each extension/user under the account? If so, I think you can call the Extension List to read information of all extensions under the account, the use the extension id to read the call log of that extension as shown above. Then when you parse the call log response, just add the name of that extension to the name column of the csv data.

Comment: Hello Mr. Vu, 
 This helps me out a great deal thanks. 
 In the code snippet you gave you are not using the var csv.  What I am after is getting everyone's outbound calls in the company for one week Monday through Friday and get counts by person or extension of how many calls were made per day and a a total.
So each row I would have:
Ext + Username, Monday count, Tuesday count ect.. through Friday then a Total of all calls for that user.